# Python Multi Threading Variables getting overwritten and mixed up

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronization

It tries to make two connections per thread now, still fails.

I think I solved the shared access thing because it uses `self.x` instead of local variables?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring
from socks import socksocket, PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from linecache import getline
from threading import Thread, current_thread, Lock, activeCount
from os.path import isfile, getmtime
from urllib import urlopen
from time import time, sleep
from sys import exit
from json import loads
from random import randint, randrange, choice
from urlparse import parse_qs
from pprint import pprint

class myThread (Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        
    def run(self):
        self.user = parse_qs(getline('./_files/ids.txt', randint(1, idLen)).strip("\n"))
        self.proxy = getline('./_files/proxies.txt', randint(1, proxyLen)).strip("\n").split(":")
        
        self.user2 = parse_qs(getline('./_files/ids.txt', randint(1, idLen)).strip("\n"))
        self.proxy2 = getline('./_files/proxies.txt', randint(1, proxyLen)).strip("\n").split(":")
        try:
            self.socket = socksocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
            self.socket.settimeout(5)
            self.socket.setproxy(PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, self.proxy[0], int(self.proxy[1]))
            
            self.socket2 = socksocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
            self.socket2.settimeout(5)
            self.socket2.setproxy(PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, self.proxy2[0], int(self.proxy2[1]))
            
            self.socket.connect((chatConnection[0], int(chatConnection[1])))
            self.socket2.connect((chatConnection[0], int(chatConnection[1])))
            
            send(self.socket, "<y r=\"%s\" v=\"0\" u=\"%s\" />\0" % (room, self.user["UserId"][0]))
            send(self.socket2, "<y r=\"%s\" v=\"0\" u=\"%s\" />\0" % (room, self.user2["UserId"][0]))
            
            self.data = read(self.socket)
            self.data2 = read(self.socket2)
            
            if self.data == "" or not self.data: return
            if self.data2 == "" or not self.data2: return
            
            self.xml = fromstring(self.data.strip(chr(0))).attrib
            self.xml2 = fromstring(self.data2.strip(chr(0))).attrib
            
            self.bSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
            self.bSock.settimeout(5)
            
            self.bSock2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
            self.bSock2.settimeout(5)
            
            self.bSock.connect(("127.0.0.1", 1337))

            send(self.bSock, "<bot p=\"%s\" yi=\"%s\" au=\"%s\"  />\0" % (self.xml["p"], self.xml["i"], self.xml["au"]))
            self.data = read(self.bSock)
            
            send(self.bSock, "<bot p=\"%s\" yi=\"%s\" au=\"%s\"  />\0" % (self.xml2["p"], self.xml2["i"], self.xml2["au"]))
            self.data2 = read(self.bSock)
            
            self.data = self.data.replace("_lol", "")
            self.l5 = self.data[self.data.find('l5="') + 4:]
            self.l5 = self.l5[:self.l5.find('"')]
            self.ya = self.data[self.data.find('c="') + 3:]
            self.ya = self.ya[:self.ya.find('"')]
            
            self.data2 = self.data2.replace("_lol", "")
            self.l52 = self.data2[self.data2.find('l5="') + 4:]
            self.l52 = self.l52[:self.l52.find('"')]
            self.ya2 = self.data2[self.data2.find('c="') + 3:]
            self.ya2 = self.ya2[:self.ya2.find('"')]
            
            print self.ya2 + " : " + self.l52
            
            self.bSock.close()
            
            self.yaSock = socksocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
            self.yaSock.settimeout(5)
            self.yaSock.setproxy(PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, self.proxy[0], int(self.proxy[1]))
            self.yaSock.connect((chatConnection[0], int(chatConnection[1])))
            
            self.yaSock2 = socksocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
            self.yaSock2.settimeout(5)
            self.yaSock2.setproxy(PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, self.proxy2[0], int(self.proxy2[1]))
            self.yaSock2.connect((chatConnection[0], int(chatConnection[1])))
            
            
            send(self.yaSock, "<ya r=\"%s\" u=\"%s\" c=\"%s\" k=\"%s\" />\0" % (room, self.user["UserId"][0], self.ya, self.xml["k"]))
            print read(self.yaSock)
            self.yaSock.close()
            
            send(self.yaSock2, "<ya r=\"%s\" u=\"%s\" c=\"%s\" k=\"%s\" />\0" % (room, self.user2["UserId"][0], self.ya2, self.xml2["k"]))
            print read(self.yaSock2)
            self.yaSock2.close()
            
            self.j2 = "<j2 Y=\"2\" l5=\"" + self.l5 + "\" l4=\"1200\" l3=\"844\" l2=\"0\" cb=\"0\" q=\"1\" y=\"" + self.xml["i"] + "\" k=\"" + self.user["k1"][0] + "\" k3=\"0\" p=\"0\" c=\"" + room + "\" f=\"2\" u=\"" + self.user["UserId"][0] + "\" d0=\"0\" n=\"Zuhnny\" a=\"1\" h=\"xat sux\" v=\"0\" />\0"
            self.j22 = "<j2 Y=\"2\" l5=\"" + self.l52 + "\" l4=\"1200\" l3=\"844\" l2=\"0\" cb=\"0\" q=\"1\" y=\"" + self.xml2["i"] + "\" k=\"" + self.user2["k1"][0] + "\" k3=\"0\" p=\"0\" c=\"" + room + "\" f=\"2\" u=\"" + self.user2["UserId"][0] + "\" d0=\"0\" n=\"Zuhnny\" a=\"1\" h=\"xat sux\" v=\"0\" />\0"

            send(self.socket, self.j2)
            send(self.socket2, self.j22)
            
            while True:
                print self.socket.recv(6096)
                print self.socket2.recv(6096)
                sleep(1)
                send(self.socket, "<m t=\" F U C K X A T %s\" u=\"%s\" />\0" % (randint(0,5000), self.user["UserId"][0]))
                send(self.socket2, "<m t=\" F U C K X A T %s\" u=\"%s\" />\0" % (randint(0,5000), self.user2["UserId"][0]))
        except IOError, err:  pass
        except Exception, error: pass
            
def read(socket):
    data = socket.recv(1024)
    return data
    
def send(socket, data):
    socket.sendall(data)
    
def getChatConnection(room):
    print '\ntest\n'
    if not isfile('./_files/ips.txt') or time() - getmtime('./_files/ips.txt') > 86400:
        fh = open('./_files/ips.txt', 'w')
        fh.write(urlopen('http://xat.com/web_gear/chat/ip2.htm?' + str(time())).read())
        fh.close()
    try:
        fh = open('./_files/ips.txt', 'r')
        iprules = loads(fh.read())
        
        Fx = iprules[iprules["order"][0][0]]
        xAddr = Fx[1][randint(0, len(Fx[1]) - 1)].split(':')
        
        if len(xAddr) == 1: xAddr.append(10000)
        if len(xAddr) == 2: xAddr.append(39)
        
        xPort = xAddr[1] + randint(0, xAddr[2] - 1)
        return (xAddr[0], 9999 + int(room) if int(room) < 8 else 10007 + (int(room) % 32))
    except Exception, e:
        print e

file = open("./_files/proxies.txt")
proxyLen = len(map(lambda(x): x.split(':'), file))

file2 = open("./_files/ids.txt")
idLen = len(map(lambda(x): x.split('\n'), file2))

threadLock = Lock()
threads = []

room = raw_input("Room ID to raid: ")
chatConnection = getChatConnection(room)

for x in range(1000):
    threads.append(myThread(x, "Thread-" + str(x)).start())

# Wait for all threads to complete
for t in threads:
    t.join()
    
print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

Comment: Tip: `'single quotes strings can double quotes (") just fine'`.

Comment: I'm aware, thank you though.

Comment: "I think threads are overwriting and/or mixing up variables and sending packets to wrong sockets etc" is a perfectly reasonable thing to suspect if you're sharing data across threads and not using locks or other synchronization anywhere. Expecting someone to read your whole mass of code and find all the race conditions is not as reasonable.

Comment: Also, why are you using `execfile` when an `import` would do the same thing better?

Comment: I apologise and I appreciate your reply. I am new to threading and Python. Can you help me out with locks & synchronization? Thanks for the reply

Comment: Thanks for the tip I'll use import!

Comment: @Jack: There's nothing Python-specific about synchronization; you need to read a good tutorial on multithreading. However, the simple rule is: anything that's only seen by one thread is guaranteed to be safe, anything that's immutable is guaranteed to be safe, anything else, have a `Lock` for it, and acquire it around every access. That may slow things down by overzealously locking, but it will resolve all race conditions, and hopefully make any deadlocks happen frequently (so they can be debugged) instead of rarely.

Comment: I've read a few tutorials but they seemed outdated and poorly worded, I don't see where I'm supposed to implement the locks where and when to acquire it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a guess at your problem. I don't think it actually is race conditions at all. I haven't read all of your code carefully, but I don't see any global or otherwise shared variables being mutated. But I do see a different problem.

You aren't buffering up your reads; you're just expecting that each `bSock.recv(1024)` is going to receive exactly one message. That isn't how TCP works; you may receive half of a message, or two messages, or the second half of the previous message and the first half of the next.

If you don't stress your computer or the network very hard, and your messages are all pretty small, it may (depending on the platform) work 99.9% of the time, meaning you don't notice any problem. But as soon as you stress things, it'll start to fail more often.

And you've got 400 threads, and from your old-style code (e.g., `except Type, value`) it looks like you may be on a system old enough that it's stuck on Python 2.5, which means you may be stressing the system very hard.

You need to fix this by receiving in a loop until you have one or more complete messages, then handling those messages, then returning to the loop, instead of handling each `recv` as if it were guaranteed to be exactly one complete message.

Fortunately, you're dealing with IRC, which (assuming you're not doing any DCC, etc.) has exactly one command per line, and Python has a nice wrapper around sockets that makes them look like line-buffered files. So you can do this:

```
bfile = bsock.makefile()
for line in bfile:
```

Now you know that `line` is guaranteed to be a complete line, even if it had to do three reads, and buffer up most of the third read until your next time through the loop.

You're doing the same thing in at least three places, so obviously you need to fix them all. Also, you need to make sure to `close` the socket and the file appropriately. And you need to detect when the other sides closes the socket. (The `recv`, or the next `line`, will return an empty string.)

Comment: But the packets are receiving properly, it's just like the the wrong data is being sent, I think it's the locking stuff you mentioned.  Example: <y room="1" v="0" u=" VALUE FROM A DIFFERENT THREAD " />

Comment: If it were receiving half a message it would also trigger a xml parse error.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

There is at least one thing all of the threads are sharing: that `bsock` socket. And they all do this 5 seconds after launch:

```
bSock.sendall("<bot p=\"%s\" au=\"%s\" yi=\"%s\" />\0" % (xml["p"], xml["au"], xml["i"]))
data = bSock.recv(1024)
```

What's to stop thread #42 from doing its `sendall`, then thread #23 doing its `sendall`, then thread #42 from doing its `recv` and getting the data intended for thread #42?

This is what's called a "critical section" or "atomic block": a chunk of code that only one thread can run at a time or everyone will get confused. The usual way around it is to share a `Lock`, and have each thread acquire the `Lock` before running this code. If thread #42 already has the lock, and thread #23 tries to acquire it, it will be blocked until thread #42 releases the lock, so there's no chance of them conflicting. So:

```
bSockLock = threading.Lock()

# ...

for x in range(400):
    Thread(target = __init__, args=[chatConnection, bSock, bSockLock]).start()

# ...

def __init__(chatConnection, bSock):
    # ...
    for x in range(3):
        start(chatConnection, proxies[x][0], proxies[x][1], [ids[x]["UserId"][0], ids[x]["k1"][0], ids[x]["k2"][0]], room, bSock, bSockLock)

# ...

def start(chatConnection, proxyIP, proxyPort, user, room, bSock, bSockLock):
    # ...
    with bSockLock:
        bSock.sendall("<bot p=\"%s\" au=\"%s\" yi=\"%s\" />\0" % (xml["p"], xml["au"], xml["i"]))
        data = bSock.recv(1024)
```

Comment: Yes! I think that's the issue, I appreciate your help and the time and effort you put into writing your answers. I have one more question though, the code you just gave, do I need to add anything? As in bSockLock.acquire or release?

Comment: So like: with bSockLock: bSockLock.acquire() do stuff, then when done bSockLock.release()?

Comment: @Jack: The `with bSockLock` does the `acquire()` automatically, and also does the `release()` automatically at the end of the indented block (even if you leave the block because of an exception). See [this article](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) explaining `with`. (You need Python 2.5 for this; if you have an older version, you'll need an `acquire` and `release`, and you usually want to use a `try`/`finally` for the `release`.)

Comment: Do I have to put this on all the socket receives and sends? There is practically no point in multi threading then because it becomes so slow, I still haven't managed to get the script working.

Comment: BSock is just connecting to a AS3 Server I have running to get a value which the IRC requries. (a bypass)

Comment: @Jack: You only have to put it on sends and receives on sockets that are shared by multiple threads. Sockets that only one thread ever sees don't need locks.

Comment: I tried that and it still failed, I tried recoding it multiple times, look at my question.  I'll put my latest one in.

Comment: What if I do this:                                                 mydata = threading.local()
mydata.x = 1

Comment: @Jack: For globals, yes, you can do that, but you don't seem to have any globals you're sharing that way, at least not in the code you posted. And, even if you were, given that your threads are all handled by a `Thread` subclass, it would be simpler (and more efficient, and cleaner for other reasons) to just move any such accidental globals to instance variables instead of using thread-locals.